# How to filter a Spark dataframe by a boolean column?

Tags: python, apache-spark, filter, apache-spark-sql

I created a dataframe that has the following schema:

```
In [43]: yelp_df.printSchema()
root
 |-- business_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cool: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- funny: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- stars: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- useful: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- user_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- full_address: string (nullable = true)
 |-- latitude: double (nullable = true)
 |-- longitude: double (nullable = true)
 |-- neighborhoods: string (nullable = true)
 |-- open: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- review_count: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- state: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to select only the records with the "open" column that is "true". The following command I run in PySpark returns nothing:

```
yelp_df.filter(yelp_df["open"] == "true").collect()
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're comparing data types incorrectly. `open` is listed as a Boolean value, not a string, so doing `yelp_df["open"] == "true"` is incorrect - `"true"` is a string.

Instead you want to do

```
yelp_df.filter(yelp_df["open"] == True).collect()
```

This correctly compares the values of `open` against the Boolean primitive `True`, rather than the non-Boolean string `"true"`.

Comment: The above snippet yields: `comparison to True should be 'if cond is True:' or 'if cond:'flake8(E712)`. As far as I tested, `yelp_df.filter(yelp_df["open"]).collect()` behaves the same and is safer/more-pythonic.

Comment: Why not to use simper df.filter(F.col('my_bool_col'))

Comment: @MrAbelash Because it doesn't help the OP understand their mistake. I'd rather make sure people learn skills rather than snippets.

Answer (score 17):

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

filtered_df = df.filter(F.col('my_bool_col'))
```

Answer (score 4):

For those who wonder how to write the opposite condition (when the column is False), it is done this way:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

filtered_df = df.filter(~F.col('my_bool_col'))
```

Answer (score 3):

In Spark - Scala, I can think of two approaches
        Approach 1 :Spark sql command to get all the bool columns by creating a temporary view and selecting only Boolean columns from the whole dataframe. However this requires Boolean columns to be determined or fteching columsn from schema based on data type

```
    //define bool columns 
    val SqlBoolCols ="'boolcolumn1','boolcolumn2','boolcolumn3' 

    dataframe.createOrReplaceTempView("Booltable")
    val dfwithboolcolumns = sqlcontext.sql(s"Select ${SqlBoolCols} from Booltable")
```

Approach 2 : Filter the dataframe if schema is defined

```
val strcolnames = rawdata.schema.fields.filter(x=>x.dataType == StringType).map(strtype=>strtype.name)   
val strdataframe= rawdata.select(strcolnames.head,strcolnames.tail:_*)
```

Comment: This theoretically might be a solution. However, just posting a code snippet is **not** a good answer. Please refer to [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and edit the question accordingly.

Comment: I have added my detailed description, possible to remove neagtive score now?

Comment: Sure, can due ;)

Comment: Thank you so much.  Do I still miss anything? zero is more encouraging than -1 :)

Comment: But this one isn‘t from me. If people like your answer they will upvote it. No need for begging.

Comment: The problem is also that you answered a question that is more then 3 years old. Furthermore, this question already has an accepted answer. Avoid answers that might not offer additional value.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're on PySpark, from `filters` documentation:

[`filter(condition)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html) - condition is a [Column](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column) of [types.BooleanType](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.types.BooleanType) or a string of SQL expression.

Since `open: boolean (nullable = true)`, the following works and avoids Flake8's E712 error:

`yelp_df.filter(yelp_df["open"]).collect()`